# ContentProvider notifyChange getting ignored

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, loader, contentobserver

We have an AsyncTaskLoader in which in the function `loadInBackground` we query a content provider.
On return of the query we get a cursor from the provider.
Now on this cursor we have set a `ForceLoadContentObserver` as below :

```
private final ForceLoadContentObserver mObserver = new ForceLoadContentObserver();
cursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
```

Now when we change a particular file, the provider has done `notifyChange`.
In normal cases, this notifyChange triggers the loadInBackground of my loader which will then requery the provider for fresh data.
But in some cases, the `loadInBackground` is not triggered on `notifyChange`.

**Reason:**
When a notifyChange is done by ContentProvider, my loader's loadInBackground is called on some worker thread.
In issue scenario my loadinBackground is not finished and the provider do a new notifyChange.
It seems that the new notifyChange is ignored by the system.

What can be the solution for this?